# Dice game, number of permutations and overall probability

Tags: probability, permutations

This question is on one of the past exam papers but I can't see to be able to get started on it. Here is the question:

Alexi and Boris are playing a game of dice. Alexi rolls three dice and records
the largest value as A. Boris rolls two dice and records the largest value as B. The player with the greatest recorded value wins the game.

(i) Show that $P(A = i) = \frac{i^3 - (i - 1)^3}{216}$ for $i = 1,2...6$

I started counting the number of permutations of each by hand (and dividing by 216) which gave the correct answer, but, after A = 3, the number of them become very large. Could someone show me a faster way to calculate this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:

$P(A=i)=P(A\leq i)-P(A\leq i-1)$

Comment: Because it is limited to just across the range of i is 1..6 I think it is just necessary here to compute P(A=1) and show it is equal to the above formula etc. Could you explain how I can calculate P(A=4) for example, from the information given?

Comment: If the $D_1,D_2,D_3$ are the scores of the $3$ dice then $P(A\leq 4)=P(D_1\leq4,D_2\leq4,D_3\leq4)=(\frac46)^3$ (the $D_j$ are independent). Likewise you find $P(A\leq3)=(\frac36)^3$. Now you can apply my hint to find $P(A=4)$.

Comment: You are very welcome.